# Update event with outlook rest api fails with Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, rest, outlook, outlook-restapi

I have an application that uses the outlook REST API for creating events on the user's calendar. The creation of the event works perfectly, but once I tried to to exactly as [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#UpdateeventsUpdateacalendareventREST) post indicates, I get **405 Method Not Allowed**.

the error details are as follow:

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidRequest","message":"The OData request is not supported."}}
```

here's a part of my code:

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events/"+meeting.OutlookEventId));

    var auth = "Bearer " + token;
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);

    var converters = new List<JsonConverter>();
    converters.Add(new MyStringEnumConverter());

    var createResponse = @"{
      'Location': {
        'DisplayName': 'Your office'
      }
    }";

    request.Content = new StringContent(createResponse);
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

I have the user token sotred on the "token" variable, as well as the outlook event Id on the "meeting.OutlookEventId" variable.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like a total fool...

I was sending a POST when this request required a PATCH

I just replaced

```
HttpMethod.Post
```

for

```
new HttpMethod("PATCH")
```